# Populating UIView with results of NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, closures

I am using an API that returns JSON which is parsed into a String.  I want to then use this string as a label on another view controller.  I tried using completion blocks but I can't get it to work, it continuously returns "Fatal error: expected optional returned nil" but I can't figure out where.  I'm assuming it has something to do with asynchronous calls not allowing the popup class to populate with the String that the API hasn't returned yet.

```
    func summarizeArticle(finished: () -> Void) {
    let formatText = (searchText.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_"))!
    articleNameFormatted = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + formatText)
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.url = NSURL(string: urlString + articleNameFormatted) as URL!
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let url = request.url
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                articleSummary = parsedData["sm_api_content"] as! String
                print(articleSummary)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
    finished()
}


@IBAction func summarizeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    summarizeArticle{
        let popupVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopupVC") as! PopupViewController
        popupVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.addChildViewController(popupVC)
        self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
        popupVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

The second view controller then uses this function which is supposed to grab the text from a global variable set by the previous functions:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    popupView.clipsToBounds = true

    summaryText.text = articleSummary

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    self.showAnimation()
}
```

Comment: "but I can't get it to work." You are telling us what its supposed to do, but what did YOU try AND what is **not working** ? what *Errors* do you encounter?

Comment: "but I can't figure out where" then debug! Put breakpoints and step till you crash.

Comment: Use optional binding to avoid issues like this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `articleSummary` a global variable, try this:

1) Make `articleSummary` local to your `summarizeArticle()` function.

2) In the class definition for your view controller with identifier `"sbPopupVC"`, add an instance variable called something like `articleSummaryText`.

3) Get rid of the completion handler on `summarizeArticle()` and move all the code that was in there to the completion block of your `URLSession` API call.

4) In that completion block, right before `self.addChildViewController(popupVC)`, add this line: `popupVC.articleSummaryText = articleSummary`

5) Finally, in `viewDidLoad()` of your popupVC, set `summaryText.text = articleSummaryText`.